# String gets transferred by libusb, but the printer wont print

Tags: c++, c, printing, libusb

I am using the tutorial at this [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148707-introduction-to-using-libusb-10/%22Link%22) to send a string to get it printed. However, even though the printer says "receving data" the data does not get printed. In the code itself libusb_bulk_transfer returns the number of characters in the string that i want to print.

Does any one have any clue as to what I might be doing wrong? Maybe i should point out that i am working with OsX and the printer works fine when i try to print a file following the regular procedure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a string to a modern raster image or *page* printer is unlikely to have the desired effect (i.e. it won't print the string) - the printer will try to interpret it as command or image data.  The control of any specific printer is specific to that model of printer, and on a modern printer is rather complex.  For example most inkjet printers, the host PC generates a raster image and sends the image data.  For PostScript printers a *page description* in the PostScript language (similar to a PDF document) is generated and sent to the printer.

The OS prints through the printer driver; the OS builds the page description in its own format, and the printer driver translates that to the printer proprietary format.

If you want to print text you must normally do that through operating system services (unless you are writing the printer driver itself), not by direct data transfer over USB.  The only exception to that perhaps is when you have a PostScript file and a PostScript printer - then that file is already in the printer's language.

Moreover in USB, printing devices are already a defined [device class](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/usbprint11a021811.pdf). This allows you to obtain information about the printer and its capabilities so that you can access it appropriately (again the job of the printer driver and OS)